# JavaScript split string to array of int

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string that's on the page and from which I want an array of int.

```
<div id="TheData">2,3,0,43,23,53</div>
```

I'm writing this:

```
var ArrayData = ($('#TheData').html()).split(',');
```

However, `ArrayData` becomes an array of strings. How can I get an array of ints? Note that some of the elements in the HTML can be equal to `0`.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To convert all elements in an array to integer in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437916/to-convert-all-elements-in-an-array-to-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
var ArrayData = $.map($('#TheData').text().split(','), function(value){
    return parseInt(value, 10);
    // or return +value; which handles float values as well
});
```

You can use `$.map` to transform the array of strings to ints by calling `parseInt` on each of the elements in the array

Comment: It should be `$.map($('#TheData').text().split(','), function(){...});`.

Comment: Note: This isn't an example of [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/), but of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: This returned an array of NaN, needed to add function (n) ... parseInt(n, 10).

Comment: Sorry about that guys @FelixKling thank you for setting me straight

Comment: @frenchie Check out the [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) implementation for support of `Array#map` in older browsers. Or the [ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) for a collection of them.

Comment: @FelixKling: yes, your answer works; you should post it as such.

Comment: Can you please give me the exact alternative in Javscript? I used `var data = parseInt(a.split(","));` but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 70):

```
var ArrayData = $('#TheData').html().split(',').map( Number );
```

Add `Array.prototype.map()` to older browsers with the code [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

---

You can use jQuery's `$.map()` in the same manner, though it won't work with `$.prototype.map()`.

```
var ArrayData = $.map( $('#TheData').html().split(','), Number );
```

Comment: This will only return integers if there are only strings that convert to integers in the array.

Comment: @kennebec: Well, yes. I'm afraid I don't understand the point you're making.

Comment: If the end-user alters the text to include decimals, you could end up with floats instead of ints. That may be okay in some scenarios, but it could cause unexpected results for those not expecting them.

Answer (score 27):

Pure Javascript solution:

```
const elementText = document.getElementById('divSourceID').innerText;
const numericList = elementText.split(',').map(Number);
```

**For more information**:

1. **getElementById**: "The Document method getElementById() returns an Element object representing the element whose id property matches the specified string. Since element IDs are required to be unique if specified, they're a useful way to get access to a specific element quickly. (...)". **Source**: [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
2. **Array.prototype.map**: "The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array". **Source**: [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
3. **array.map(Number)**: This call means the first received argument will be automatically converted into number and results in the same as if you explicitly declare the arrow function:

```
const numericList = elementText.split(',').map(Number);
```

*same result as:*

```
const numericList = elementText.split(',').map(str => Number(str));
```

JIT: Special thanks to @Robbendebiene for the excellent code review, simplifying the previous code.

Comment: This function can be simplified to: `elementText.split(',').map(Number);`

Comment: Excellent point @Robendebiene, thank you. I will update my answer as some of the code I wrote as not necessary (split already returns an array, for example).

Good catch. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

```
var ArrayData = $('#TheData').text().split(',').map(Number);
```

You can find more here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple answer

```
let x = "1,2,3,4";

let result = x.split(",").map((e) => parseInt(e));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Easy to understand and does the job!

Answer (score 2):

```
var ArrayData = $('#TheData').html().split(',').map( d => { return parseInt(d) });
```

Use **map** function after **Split**, in callback of map you can parse that Integer

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! My apologies if I'm missing something, but isn't your answer pretty much what was already posted as the accepted answer?