# removing double quotes from an array with .spilt()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove double quotes from a string so it becomes like a number but i'm finding it hard to do.

```
 for ( let i = 0 ; i < this.advanceSaveList.length; i++) {
    if (this.advanceSaveList) {
    this.advanceSearchSelectedGrades = [this.advanceSaveList[i].properties.gradeIds.replace (/"/g,'')];

  }
```

With the code above the results returns like `["58,59"]` but i want it to return like `[58, 59]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript split string to array of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232776/javascript-split-string-to-array-of-int)

Comment: Why are you use an if condition?

Comment: So is `gradeIds` a nested array?

Comment: Does the string *have* double quotes in it? Or are you looking at the *string representation*? A string of `"hello world"` may have double quotes when printed in the console to denote it's a string, in reality the *content* of it is `hello world` - 11 characters.

Comment: @silencedogood, yes its a nested array

Comment: If you have a string that contains *a number*, you can parse it and obtain the number.

Comment: @Cid, the link you provide returns the results with double quotes, so it doesn't solve my issue

Comment: `"58,59".split(',').map( Number );` gives `[58, 59]` as output. no double quotes.