# ParseInt a string to numbers in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert a string of numbers into an array of elements with each number. I thought parseInt would convert the string to numbers but I'm a bit lost now.

```
const str = '1 2 3 4';
let words = parseInt(str);
words = str.split(' ');
```

which results in

```
Array ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

However, I would like the result to be

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Duplicate: [How to convert all elements in an array to integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437916/how-to-convert-all-elements-in-an-array-to-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a little [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do that. When you're doing a simple conversion like this, you can use a single method in the map argument as a shortcut

```
str.split(' ').map(Number)
```

is the same as

```
str.split(' ').map(n => Number(n))
```

which is the same as

```
str.split(' ').map(n => {
  return Number(n);
})
```

```js
const str = '1 2 3 4';
let words = str.split(' ').map(Number)
console.log(words);
```

Comment: Wow that's neat! I like it

Answer (score 0):

`str.split(' ').map(Number)` is not a wrong answer for the given data but what if you are given a string like `'1    2 3    4'`? The result would be `[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4]`.

So perhaps

```
[...str].reduce((r,c) => c === " " ? r : (r.push(+c),r),[]);
```

or

```
[...str].reduce((r,c) => c === " " ? r : r.concat(+c),[]);
```

might just do better.

Comment: Or use a RegExp in split()