# Store commas seperated value as an array in DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Through an input field, I am collecting values separated by commas like this "10", "20", "30" which come as an array in my req. body.

Like this req. body.options= ["10","20","30"].

I want to store each value as an array value like this

```
option[0] = 10,
option[1] = 20,
option[3] = 30,
```

but now when I store value like this

```
options = req.body.options.
```

I get results like this

```
option[0] =["10","20","30"].
```

Quite new to programming. So appreciate any sort of help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437916/how-to-convert-all-elements-in-an-array-to-integer-in-javascript this? sorry I do not have comment privileges yet

Answer (score 0):

Simply do it, using the spread operator:

```
let options = [...req.body.options];
```

Here's the link to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).